# javascript: how to loop through date object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to ask this, but is there a way to get the current local full year and then create a loop to get the last 18 years and print them to the screen?

Here is what I've tried...

```
function allYears(){
  var d = new Date();
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var years = '';
  for(var i=0; i>18; i++){
    years += '<option value="'+y+'">'+y+'</option>';
    y = y-1;
  }
return(years);
}
```

Comment: Note `d.getFullYear` should be `d.getFullYear()`

Comment: The body of your loop is never executed since `i = 0` and `0 > 18` is `false`.

Comment: +1 Felix Kling, your comment was very helpful! I set up some alerts but the for loop would never execute and I couldn't figure out why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a function:

```
function printYearsBefore(date,num) {
   var yr = parseInt(date.getFullYear()), i =0;
   while(++i <= num){
     document.write((yr-i));
   }
}

printYearsBefore(new Date(),18);
```

Comment: This only produces 17 previous years. You should change the while condition to `++i <= num`.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but two problems:

1) `d.getFullYear` should be `d.getFullYear()`, otherwise you're not getting the year, merely referencing the method

2) `> 18` should be `< 18`

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle with working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aMFpw/6/

You were very close with your original implementaion.

Javascript here:

```
  function getYears(num){
    var d  = new Date();
    var y = parseInt(d.getFullYear());

    var years = "";

    //need to add one to our number based on our loop index.
    num++;

    for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
        years += '<option value="' + y + '">' + y + '</option>';
        y--;    
    }

    return years;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest performing math on the variable that refers to the year, as you increment (or decrement) through the `for` loop, simply add, or remove, the incrementing variable (`i` in this case) to, or from, the variable holding the year:

```
function addYears(el, num) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (var i=0; i < num; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option'),
                year = new Date().getFullYear() - i;
            opt.value = year;
            opt.textContent = year;
            el.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
}

addYears(document.getElementById('years'), 18);​
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r6nED/).

In your code excerpt, I'd suggest amending things to:

```
function allYears(){
  var d = new Date();
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var years = '';
  for(var i=0; i<18; i++){
    years += '<option value="'+ (y - i) +'">'+ (y - i) +'</option>';
  }
return(years);
}
```

Which, as the loop progresses, should return `option` elements with year values progressively earlier than the year held in `y`.

Also, the middle condition in the `for` loop is the evaluation that has to be true for the loop to continue (when it stops being true is when the loop exits), so it *should* be `i < 18` (since `i` starts equal to `0`).

Comment: This code only produces the last 17 years, not 18 like the answer specifies.